# Testing the RemoveNode DOM function

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following test html:

```
<table width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" >
  <tr>
    <td class="tableBorder">
      <table id="scriptsT" name="scriptsT" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>

          <td colspan="4" class="tableTitle">&#8250; College Foo - ScriptList:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowHeaders">
          <td width="4%">ScriptName</td>
          <td width="2%">Main Script (Radio)</td>
          <td width="2%">(Ext)</td>
          <td width="2%">Del Script</td>

        </tr>
        <tr id="foo[1]" name="foo[1]" class="rowHeaders">
          <td id="sTD" name="sTD" width="4%">Script1</td>
          <td width="2%">
            <input type="radio" name="main" id="main" value="">
          </td>
          <td id="tTD" name="tTD" width="2%">Php</td>
          <td width="2%"><input type="Button" class="textbox" name="SelScript" id="" value="DelScript" onClick="javascript: DelScript(1); return false;"></td>

        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

=======================================================

I'm trying to remove the node, using the "DelScript function, that tries to use an ID to select the given TR, based on each TR having a unique ID, in this case foo[1], etc..

In my test DelScript, I 1st get the table, and then try to get the childnode (the "TR") to delete.

```
//--handle/simulate the deletion of the tr in the scriptTBL for the id
function DelScript(id)
{
    var scriptTBL=document.getElementById("scriptsT");

    var a="foo["+id+"]"

    var test=document.getElementById("foo[1]");
    //scriptTBL.parentNode.removeChild(test);
    scriptTBL.removeChild(test);

    alert("foo");
    var a;

}
```

However, I'm screwing something up, as I'm not able to delete the node.

I'm running FF4, and firefox seems to be saying the node can't be found (???).

I've also tried using the parentNode a well but get the same results.

Thank you for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to 
"delete the TR where the clicked 'delete' button is located"
You don't need any of those id attributes.

```
<input type="Button" onclick="DelScript(this);return false;">


function DelScript(theClickedButton) {
var tr = theClickedButton.parentNode.parentNode;
tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The table rows are not children of the `<table>`, they're children of the `<tbody>` element inside it. Even if there's not a `<tbody>` in your markup, there's one in the DOM. You could go up the DOM from the child element itself, or you could find the `<tbody>`

```
var tbody = document.getElementById('scriptsT').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

FF is likely inserting a `<tbody>` element in between your `<table>` and `<tr>`, as the HTML specification demands. You don't even need to know the table ID. The attempt you commented out was almost right, but you need `test.parentNode` instead of `table.parentNode` - you want to get the row's parent node, not the table's:

```
function deleteRow(n){
    var el = document.getElementById('foo['+n+']');
    return el.parentNode.removeChild( el );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The TR is not a child of the TABLE. It is a child of the TBODY that is implicitly a child of the TABLE. Try this:

```
scriptTBL.children[0].removeChild(test);
```

Also, install FireBug so that you can browse the DOM tree and set breakpoints in your scripts to examine what they are doing to the dynamically rendered HTML.